# CreateProcess error=206, Eclipse CDT with GCC compile ThreadX+GUIX

Tags: eclipse-cdt, threadx

When I compile `ThreadX+GUIX` project of eclipse CDT with `arm-none-eabi-gcc(Win7 64bit)`. It come out `make (e=206)`. I found the same problems happened almost in JAVA development,but their solutions are not work for the CDT. Here is the compile error information:
[image]
I know the reason is because the GUIX has 1311 source files, and the compile and link operation command comes beyond the 8192 command limit. I have try to update the eclipse ,and move my workspace to the root of disk ,but the error still comes out. Now I don't know how to solve this problem. Anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

If it is failing during linker/librarian stage, I modify the librarian command line to use an object_list.txt file to feed in the object file list, rather than specify them all on the command line. So something like this:

arm-elf-ar -r libguix.a @../object_list.txt

I use a python script to generate object_list.txt from the list of .c files, so it looks like this:

```
./common/src/gx_accordion_menu_create.o
./common/src/gx_accordion_menu_draw.o
./common/src/gx_accordion_menu_event_process.o
./common/src/gx_accordion_menu_position.o
./common/src/gx_animation_canvas_define.o
./common/src/gx_animation_complete.o
./common/src/gx_animation_create.o
./common/src/gx_animation_drag_disable.o
```

etc...

In your eclipse IDE there are settings to run your own custom linker command line rather than the default command line that isn't working.

Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Thank you，Kenneth Maxwell. I think the suggestion you give is right way to solve my problem.But i am just a simple eclipse user.i've tried to search the way to config my eclipse project by using custom linker file,witch comes out few results. I will keep trying to find a solution.And it would be appreciated if you have any recommends to learn.